# How to save elements in excel with pandas?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

My code does the following:

1st enter the site

2nd collects the links and saves in a dictionary

3rd the code enters the links saved in the dictionary to extract the elements and also saves in a dictionary

4th finally it saves the information of the elements that are in the dictionary in excel pandas

Problem:
Some pages do not contain information to be extracted, it is probably a bug on the site, so pandas does not save the information already collected.

Here's the error:

```
valueerror: all arrays must be of the same length
```

Here's part of my code, I didn't put it in full so it wouldn't get long.

I'm using selenium.

```
links = []
imagem = []
pacote = []

counter = 1
for linkAtual in links:
    driver.get(linkAtual)
    try:
        driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Ir para a oferta']").click()
        sleep(2)
    except:
        print("proxima pagina")

    try:
        titulo = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "h1")
        print(titulo.text)

        pacote.append(titulo.text.replace("Pacote de Viagem - ", "").replace("+", " e ").replace("2022", "").replace(
            "2023", "").replace("2024", "").replace("2025", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("-", ""))

        print("baixar imagem ")
        primeiro_caminho = driver.find_element(By. XPATH, "(//img)[2]")
        atributoSrc = primeiro_caminho.get_attribute("src")
        # file_name = f"{titulo}{counter:02d}.jpg"
        file_name = f"image{counter:02d}.jpg"
        imagem.append(atributoSrc)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(
            atributoSrc, f"C:\\__Imagens e Planilhas Python\\Afiliacoes\\Fotos\\{file_name}")
        counter += 1
    except:
        print("não tem conteudo")


data = {'Pacote': pacote, 'Link Afiliado': links}
#df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient="index")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_excel(r"C:\__Imagens e Planilhas Python\Afiliacoes\pacotes.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter')
print(df)
```

Page that doesn't work I found one, it has 300 links and about 4 that don't have information:

Here is an example of an error link:

https://www.hurb.com/br/packages/la-romana-passagem-aerea-hospedagem/1416419?utm_source=Felipe-F-clubehurb&utm_medium=clubehu-promotion&utm_campaign=689696&cmp=689696

Here are examples of valid links:

https://www.hurb.com/br/packages/costa-do-sauipe-passagem-aerea-hospedagem-all-inclusive/1421105?utm_source=Felipe-F-clubehurb&utm_medium=clubehu-product&utm_campaign=689696&cmp=689696

https://www.hurb.com/br/packages/rio-de-janeiro-passagem-aerea-hospedagem/1407451?utm_source=Felipe-F-clubehurb&utm_medium=clubehu-product&utm_campaign=689696&cmp=689696

https://www.hurb.com/br/packages/pacote-aereo-hospedagem-dubrovnik/1419049?utm_source=Felipe-F-clubehurb&utm_medium=clubehu-product&utm_campaign=689696&cmp=689696

Comment: For the values that were not collected while web scapping add np.nan for them

Comment: could you give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: can you provide me 5-6 links (both working and not working)? I will edit and share the code.

Comment: Just append an empty string or `np.nan` in pacote inside the second except where you are printing não tem conteudo

Answer (score 0):

you could edit your 2nd `try...except` block to

```py
    titlTxt, atributoSrc = None, None # initiate/clear as null
    try:
        titulo = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "h1")
        print(titulo.text)

        # pacote.append... # outside block
        titlTxt = titulo.text.replace("Pacote de Viagem - ", "").replace("+", " e ").replace("2022", "").replace(
            "2023", "").replace("2024", "").replace("2025", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("-", "")

        print("baixar imagem ")
        primeiro_caminho = driver.find_element(By. XPATH, "(//img)[2]")
        atributoSrc = primeiro_caminho.get_attribute("src")
        # file_name = f"{titulo}{counter:02d}.jpg"
        file_name = f"image{counter:02d}.jpg"
        # imagem.append(atributoSrc) # outside block
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(
            atributoSrc, f"C:\\__Imagens e Planilhas Python\\Afiliacoes\\Fotos\\{file_name}")
        counter += 1
    except:
        print("não tem conteudo")

    pacote.append(titlTxt)
    imagem.append(atributoSrc)
```

so now `pacote` and `imagem` should have exactly one item [each] corresponding to each item in `links`, so all 3 lists can be expected to be of the same length.

(If you had separate `try...except` blocks for each list, you could `append` in both `try` and in `except`; but when extracting for multiple lists in the same `try`, some of them might already be appended to before raising an exception, so appending in `except` as well risks adding to the same list twince in a single loop.)